# Stop a Commit underway

Tags: github, github-for-mac, github-desktop

I accidentally commit a large file (several gigabytes) from the Github Desktop for Mac client. The commit is extremely time-consuming, and I would prefer to stop it rather than wait for the commit to finish.

Does Github Desktop have any sort of "stop commit" button for situations like this?

Answer (score 0):

To stop any command in your command prompt or terminal, just type `ctrl + c`

Comment: how about if it's Github Desktop?